# How to pass in a json file to sigmajs

Tags: javascript, json, sigma.js

So I am trying to learn SigmaJS and am having difficulty understanding how to pass the data.json to the JS in this codepen:

http://codepen.io/eternalminerals/pen/GpqNLQ

For example, the http://sigmajs.org/ website has a simple example as follows:

Data:

```
{
  "nodes": [
    {
      "id": "n0",
      "label": "A node",
      "x": 0,
      "y": 0,
      "size": 3
    },
    {
      "id": "n1",
      "label": "Another node",
      "x": 3,
      "y": 1,
      "size": 2
    },
    {
      "id": "n2",
      "label": "And a last one",
      "x": 1,
      "y": 3,
      "size": 1
    }
  ],
  "edges": [
    {
      "id": "e0",
      "source": "n0",
      "target": "n1"
    },
    {
      "id": "e1",
      "source": "n1",
      "target": "n2"
    },
    {
      "id": "e2",
      "source": "n2",
      "target": "n0"
    }
  ]
}
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
  #container {
    max-width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: auto;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container"></div>
<script src="sigma.min.js"></script>
<script src="sigma.parsers.json.min.js"></script>
<script>
  sigma.parsers.json('data.json', {
    container: 'container',
    settings: {
      defaultNodeColor: '#ec5148'
    }
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried passing in the data.json as follows:

```
sigma.parsers.json('http://eternalminerals.com/data/data.json', {
    container: 'container',
    settings: {
      defaultNodeColor: '#ec5148'
    }
  });
```

but it doesn't seem to be working. How do you pass in the data.json given that the data.json file is located at http://eternalminerals.com/data/data.json ?

Comment: You actually have a cross-domain error in codepen, did you test in local with no cross-domain issue?

Comment: oh wow.. thank you so much http://eternalminerals.com/testb/ works actually. I guess I have a habit of things not working locally so I try it out on codepen first. Thank you so much, romuleald!!